# How to change the current_user in rails with devise since sign_in is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I'm using Devise 4.7.1, Rails 6.0.

Even if trying with byebug this does not work:

```
(byebug) user.id
1
(byebug) current_user.id
22
(byebug) sign_in(user)
#<User id: 1, ...>
(byebug) current_user.id
22
```

In my application the page is then improperly rendered (wrong user). A refresh solves it, showing the session is properly mapped to the user #1, but since current_user is not altered.

Might this be a problem with devise as I'm not using `database_authenticatable` (Authenticatable module) since I'm not using passwords for verification?

Comment: can you check if `warden.set_user user` work?

Comment: @RifatulIslamChayon didn't help. warden is properly set (`warden.user != current_user`), everything in warden looks perfect. Just `current_user` is outdated. I sort it out by using a redirect instead of rendering the page directly. It is still kind of strange... Is it supposed to work? I mean to change `current_user`?